# Removing Nth line of File with BufferedReader/BufferedWriter

Tags: java, file

So I have a text file structured like this (product,price,category,quantity).

```
Apple
1.0
Fruits
120
Cucumber
1.4
Vegetables
110
Pear
1.6
Fruits
120
```

I need a function that can remove the Nth item, in this case the second item form the file (which are lines 5,6,7,8), so it'd look like this:

```
Apple
1.0
Fruits
120
Pear
1.6
Fruits
120
```

All I can find are ways to remove a specific string from file, but that's not what I need in this case.

Edit:
Here's my code so far:

```
int place=2;            
try{
    File inputFile = new File("Cart.txt"); 
    File tempFile = new File("Cart1.txt"); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    int itemToRemove=place*4;
    String currentLine;
    int line=0;
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line!=itemToRemove||line!=itemToRemove+1||line!=itemToRemove+2||line!=itemToRemove+3){
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        line++;
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
    tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
}catch(Exception x){}
```

It should remove the second item from the file but it just makes a copy

Comment: Please show us your code and explain in detail what the problem is.

Comment: I guess this is homework so you have to show some code

Comment: Also you can read file and remove the items and rewrite to same file

Comment: Use Files class to stream/loop through each line and remove whichever you need.

Comment: I've updated my post with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is run your code with a debugger to discover that your `if` condition is incorrect and that incrementing `line` should be the first operation performed inside the `while` loop.

Here is your code with my corrections.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class RemovNth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int place = 2;
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("Cart.txt");
            File tempFile = new File("Cart1.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
            int itemToRemove = (place - 1) * 4;
            String currentLine;
            int line = -1;
            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                line++;
                if (line == itemToRemove || line == itemToRemove + 1 || line == itemToRemove + 2
                        || line == itemToRemove + 3) {
                    continue;
                }
                writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, according to the documentation, method `renameTo` may fail.

Your `if` condition will **always** be true.